# Can anyone solve integral $\int ( a + b \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x} )^{n} dx $?

Tags: integration

Does anybody know a general solution to the integral

$$\int ( a + b \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x} )^{n} dx $$

where $a, b, \lambda, n \in \mathbb{R}$?

The above integral is related to a physics problem, for which analytical solution would be very nice to have.

I appreciate all the comments. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to mention that a, b, lambda and n are real constants

Comment: What have you tried? It is recommended to show your effort when [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/595055).

Comment: Is it a definite integral?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Exploiting the binomial expansion and linearity of the integral, one gets
\begin{align*}
\int(a+be^{-\lambda x})^n\,dx
&=\int\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^ke^{-\lambda kx}\,dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k\left(\int e^{-\lambda kx}\,dx\right)\;.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Using @Alex's nice substitution, we end with
$$I_n=-\frac{a^n}\lambda \int \frac {(1+t)^n}t \,dt$$ and
$$\int \frac {(1+t)^n}t \,dt=\frac{(1+t)^{n+1} }{n t}\,\, _2F_1\left(1,1;1-n;-\frac{1}{t}\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function.